HashMaps and returning immutable references to inserted keys with std's HashMap (was reference demoting?)
EDIT: After mulling over this topic for a bit, I've become unsure if such an api is inherently possible at all with rust's borrow checker.
So, the APIs I'm trying to achieve (if it did exist in HashMap) would look somewhat like:

fn insert_and<'a> (&'a mut self, key: K, value: V) -> (&'a K, &'a V)
fn entry_view(&mut self, key: K) -> EntryView<'_, K, V>

So, our objective is to get a reference to the inserted key and value without additional lookups, preferably similar to the Entry API.
However, since we need the ability to insert the key-value pair if it does not exist, we do need to take a mutable reference to self (otherwise we'll just be doing get() with extra steps!)
And because this means that lifetime 'a is tied to a mutable reference, the returned reference &'a K, with lifetime 'a, is also treated as a mutable reference by the borrow checker! (Context: reference demoting 1 2)
And - while this may be a misunderstanding on my part - rust doesn't seem to have a way to demote a mutable reference to immutable references whose lifetime is constrained to self, even with unsafe code. i.e.:
fn foo<'a, 'b> (&'a mut self) -> &'b Foo {
    unsafe { ... }
}

does not work - 'b is not tied to self, and allows mutable borrows/drops while &'b Foo is active.
Thus, the above proposed APIs, while logically fine, would simply act as a mutable reference to self - which undermines a lot of functionality that we were trying to achieve that wasn't possible with the Entry API.
Go figure.
IndexMap genuinely does seem like the best choice without all this lifetime mishap.

I have encountered two problems which seem simple enough, but for which I cannot seem to find an easy way to achieve in std's (or hashbrown's) HashMap. The IndexMap crate seems to be a viable solution - but the problem seems like it should be doable in std. Am I missing something here?
The first problem is getting a reference to an inserted key which is returnable:
struct Foo<K, V> {
    map: HashMap<K, V>
}

impl<K, V> Foo<K, V>
where
    K: Hash + Eq
{
    fn foo(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> (&K, &V) {
        //Insert and return (&K, &V) somehow
    }
}

The easy way would of course be constraining K to Clone and cloning the key before insertion, but that a) introduces unnecessary constraints, and b) is rather inefficient (clone + double lookup)
Instead, I would like to:

get a reference key after the insertion without additional lookups (preferably something akin to the Entry API)
the reference to have a lifetime tied to the owning HashMap (as opposed with OccupiedEntry or the likes).

The Entry API was my first guess at tackling this problem - and the entry_insert feature (to be stabilized in rust 1.83 :D) seemed to be promising; it returns a OccupiedEntry instead of a &'a mut V like most other functions.
Except, the Entry struct can only get a &K (constrained to the lifetime of the Entry object), not a &'a K (like the into_mut function).
A alternative method I found was by using the raw_entry feature, and this does indeed seem promising; the functions return a (&'a mut K, &'a mut V), which can then be casted into a (&'a K, &'a V). Great!
Except... as of Aug 17, this feature seems have undergone the deprecation process, which means that this will most likely soon be removed from nightly and stable (unless I'm mistaken, of course - I'm not terribly familiar with the rustlang processes). A comment do say that high-level functionality should be achievable with entry_ref, and low-level functionality should be achievable with HashTable - except this doesn't seem complex/exotic enough to be considered a 'low-level functionality', and the entry_ref implementation on the hashbrown crate doesn't seem to have any ability to retrieve a &'a K, much like its sister.
Of course, if we're going to import hashbrown anyway, we might just as well use the raw_entry present in the crate - except this (and the matching std function) seems to have a new problem arise: even though we casted the mutable references to immutable references, rust's borrow checker treats it as a mutable reference to the map.
This leads to the second problem - getting a immutable reference to an inserted key:
struct Bar<'a, K> {
    map: &'a HashMap<K, K>,
    entry: OccupiedEntry<'a, K, K> // or some variant
}

struct Foo<K> {
    map: HashMap<K, K>
}

impl<K, V> Foo<K, K>
where
    K: Hash + Eq
{
    fn foo<'a> (&'a mut self, key: K, value: K) -> Bar<'a, K> {
        let entry = self.map.entry(key)
            .insert_entry(value)
        
        Bar {
            // This isn't possible because `entry` acts as a mutable reference to `self.map`
            map: &self.map,
            entry
        }
    }
}

(Note that the value type is equal to the key type K now to better illustrate the problem; the first problem used V to avoid confusion)
As you can probably see, this is a problem that I encountered while trying to work around the above problem; this eliminates the need for the reference to not depend on the Entry structs. However, I also needed to store the reference to the hashmap to perform lookups with the value in the entry.
This alone would be a bit exotic - but the problem here essentially boils down to obtaining a view to an inserted entry which is treated as an immutable reference; i.e. we need to:

get a reference key after the insertion without additional lookups (preferably something akin to the Entry API)
the reference to act as a immutable reference to the HashMap.

All versions of entry, entry_ref, and raw_entry_mut takes a &mut self in its signature, which seems to mean that they are treated as a mutable reference to the HashMap itself, even if we cast them to immutable references. Understandable, since they do have the functionality of mutating the entry - but which is quite unfortunate for us, since it means that we can't apply the above workaround.
What's more, this limit means that we can't solve this even without adhering to the first requirement; since the entries are treated as a mutable reference to the struct, the borrow checker limits us from performing a get() while holding a Entry - or a get_key_value() with the obtained Entry, either.
Given these complications, IndexMap seem to be the best solution to the above. I'm not sure if performing insert_full and get_index does double lookups or not, but worrying about this is probably premature optimization. However, do we really need to introduce an additional crate for this? This seems like such a basic functionality to not be doable in the std.

The first request is very reasonable. Although I also cannot see such API, you can propose it (the process will be to open an API Change Proposal).
The second however... Such API could exist by returning some marker into the newly inserted entry that does not carry a lifetime (e.g. the index of the new entry), however the marker will be invalidated by any growth (or shrink) of the map. As such, this is a highly exotic API, and also very fragile and easy to misuse. I cannot imagine a situation in which such API finds its way into std. Unfortunately, even with hashbrown's raw HashTable it seems impossible to implement this, although there it might be a reasonable request, given that this is an inherently low-level API.

I've been trying to see how the first API is fine, while the second is not - and I've run into a problem which seems to also invalidate the first API. I've edited the question to acknowledge this dilemma, but the basic gist is:
Both APIs are asking to get a immutable reference from a function which takes a mutable reference to self. This, as I've found out, seems impossible to achieve without reference demotion implemented in the borrow checker.

@riveroon I explained how the second API can be done. The first API has no problem.
